# Raspberry pi error looking for libd|.so

Tags: docker

I rebooted my raspberry pi and then attempted to run `docker ps` but got this crazy error:

`docker: error while loading shared libraries: libd|.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Note the library name: libd + pipe character.  No idea what happened here and whether it was some kind of memory corruption and looking for libd, but reinstalling docker and rebooting it fixed the problem (kind of wish I hadn't reinstalled docker since I think the fix was just reboot).  I had no luck at all googling for this error, but I'm not sure if that is because special characters are harder to google for.

Does anybody have any insight into what might have caused this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-bit error while reading the Docker executable from your SD card.

The difference between `|` (0x7c) and `l` (0x6c) is a single bit. The correct filename was almost certainly `libdl.so.0`.